# Can I move through an ally in Combat?

Tags: warhammer-40k, deathwatch, dark-heresy-1e, rogue-trader

The three Warhammer 40k RPGs (Dark Heresy, Rogue Trader, Deathwatch) share a somewhat common ruleset, and I believe this question applies to all three.

Can I move through an ally in combat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following response was from Mack Martin of Fantasy Flight Games:

> This is a tricky question to answer,
>   as the game isn't distinctly designed
>   with battle mat play in mind. While a
>   grid can certainly be useful in a game
>   (and add some fun strategizing into
>   combat) it would really depend on how
>   much space a single square represents.
>   In my games (and generally speaking)
>   if a square was 3 or more meters then
>   I would declare that you can move
>   through allied squares without issue.
>   If it were less (such as 1) then I
>   would suggest that the character must
>   go around. I would also say that if
>   forced too, a character can squeeze
>   through a space occupied by a friend
>   (if each square is 1 meter) by
>   spending 3 meters of move distance to
>   get through.
>
> 3 metres per square feels like a lot
>   of space, a 1 meter square, however,
>   might get out of hand if a character
>   can run 18 meters in a round. This is
>   really something the GM and Players
>   will have to figure out on their own.
>
> None of this is official, obviously,
>   but hopefully these guidelines can
>   help your group come up with some
>   suitable house rules for using a grid
>   mat during your game sessions.

Not a firm answer, but it will have to do.

Answer (score -1):

I'd just treat it as a dodge roll to get by, at the better character's dodge, and count it as 2 squares instead of 1.

Looking in Deathwatch, I can find nothing to indicate otherwise.
However, if one wanted to be thoroughly pedantic, one could declare engagement on the friend, and then disengage, making it a half-move or move followed by a disengage (which includes a half-move).

Comment: -1 - I think the Questioner is asking for a definitive rules answer which you did not provide.

Comment: Needed time to dig out books, and any answer after 3 days without answer, I felt some answer better than no answer at all.